# Ubuntu 20.04 Gnome VNC problem

Tags: 20.04, gnome, vnc, gdm

I use tigervnc server, gnome, on ubuntu 20.04. The problem is, if I lock the screen from VNC viewer then I will never able to login again from VNC. I still can type the password, but even if I hit enter it does not login. However, if I start vnc server with: vncserver command, then the problem does not occur.

~/.vnc/xstartup

```
#!/bin/sh
[ -x /etc/vnc/xstartup ] && exec /etc/vnc/xstartup
[ -r $HOME/.Xresources ] && xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
```

/etc/vnc/xstartup

```
# !/bin/sh

test x"$SHELL" = x"" && SHELL=/bin/bash
test x"$1"     = x"" && set -- default

vncconfig -iconic &
"$SHELL" -l <<EOF
export XDG_SESSION_TYPE=x11
dbus-launch --exit-with-session gnome-session
exec /etc/X11/Xsession "$@"
EOF
vncserver -kill $DISPLAY
```

/etc/systemd/system/vncserver@.service

```
[Unit]
Description=Start TigerVNC server at startup
After=syslog.target network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=john
PAMName=login
PIDFile=/home/john/.vnc/%H:%i.pid
ExecStartPre=-/usr/bin/vncserver -kill :%i > /dev/null 2>&1
ExecStart=/usr/bin/vncserver -fg -depth 24 -geometry 1280x1024 -localhost no :%i
ExecStop=/usr/bin/vncserver -kill :%i
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: Try to remove `ExecStop=/usr/bin/vncserver -kill :%i` from the unit file `vncserver@.service`

Comment: I tried, but did not help unfortunately.

Comment: In my system I'm using x0vncserver which is installable by `sudo apt-get install tigervnc-scraping-server`. To start it at boot I have decided to create a bash script and launch it by Autostart of the desktop manager (see Preferences--> Autostart and so on) but I don't know if you can install this VNC server in your system. I'm using lubuntu 22.04

Comment: Do you use it with gnome? Can you share your config with me? That would be a big help. Thanks!

Comment: try "loginctl unlock-sessions"

Comment: @petep "loginctl unlock-sessions" doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

### Installation of x0vncserver

On lubuntu 22.04 I have installed x0vncserver by the command:

```
sudo apt-get install tigervnc-scraping-server
```

May be it is better that you remove your current VNC server.

After the installation I have executed the following steps:

```
> mkdir -p ~/.vnc

> vncpasswd
# insert the VNC password (not create a password for only Viewer 
# connection when the command ask you)
```

### Creation of the x0vncserver starting script

Create the following script `/usr/local/bin/start-x0vncserver.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

export XAUTHORITY="/var/run/lightdm/root/:0"

VNC_BIN=/usr/bin/x0vncserver

PARAMS="-localhost no -passwordfile ~/.vnc/passwd -display :0"

($VNC_BIN $PARAMS)

exit 0
```

Previous script enable VNC Client to connect to the display:0 (see the parameter `-display :0` for the VNC server `x0vncserver`).

This script must be executable so execute:

```
> sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/start-x0vncserver.sh
```

### Enable the autostart of VNC Server

After that, you have to enable the execution of the script `/usr/local/bin/start-x0vncserver.sh` at boot by the Autostart function of Ubuntu. On lubuntu 22.04 I have used the menu `Preference->LXQT Settings->Session Settings->Autostart` (from Start button).

On your Ubuntu distribution I don't know exactly where you can find the option for Autostart but I'm sure is under the `Preferences` menu of the Start button.

Comment: x0vncserver seems fine, but unfortunately it acts differently from TigerVNC. Unlike TigerVNC, it does not create a virtual display. Instead, it just shares an existing X server (typically, that one connected to the physical screen). I would like to create a virtual display for each VNC client.